# How to export nested list and dictionaries from python to excel

Tags: excel, python-2.7, list, dictionary, nested

Hi I'm currently running a program which acts as a TCP/IP socket for an eyetracker called eyetribe, its derived from a module from GitHub under the name of Pytribe. I want to export the values which I obtain for the X,Y co-ordinates and the timestamp to Excel. I am using xlsxwriter, however, its unable to export as new values are constantly being generated. Any help on how to write a code so that the values of X and Y print in Excel. Currently, I have not imported xlsxwriter in this program for clarity

```
import time, socket, Queue, 

def jprint(your_json):
import json
parsed = json.loads(your_json)
return json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True)


def query_tracker(message="""
                {
                    "category": "tracker",
                    "request" : "get",
                    "values": [ "frame" ]
                }""",
              get_status=False, host='localhost',
              port=6555, buffer_size=1024,
              ):
"""Directly query the eye-tribe tracker.

Data is returned as a nested set of dictionaries and lists.
The eye tracker server must be running and calibrated.
Use get_status=True to over-ride message and query status."""

import socket
import json
import time
if get_status == True:
    message = """{
        "category": "tracker",
        "request" : "get",
        "values": [ "push", "iscalibrated" ]
    }"""

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))
s.send(message)
#pause to allow message to come through
time.sleep(0.01)
data = s.recv(buffer_size)
s.close()
try: parsed = json.loads(data)
except ValueError: parsed = None
return parsed

def extract_queue(q, l=None):
if l == None: l = []

while True:
    try:
        l.append(q.get(block=False))
    except Queue.Empty:
        return l
        break


def connect_to_tracker(host = 'localhost', port = 6555, buffer_size = 1024):
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))
return s


def queue_tracker_frames(queue, message=None, interval=0.01, loop_limit=None):
"""Read data from tracker in PUSH mode.

Data is pushed into queue as it arrives, once per interval seconds.
Does not play well with interval > 0.4
"""
if message == None:
    message="""
    {
        "category": "tracker",
        "request": "set",
        "values": {
            "push": true,
            "version": 1
        }
    }"""

import json
s = connect_to_tracker()
s.send(message)
_ = s.recv(2**15)  # Discard first response

loop = 0
while True:
    loop += 1
    time.sleep(interval)
    data = s.recv(2**15)
    data_list = [json.loads(line) for line in data.split('\n')
                 if line.split()]
    for point in data_list:
        queue.put(point)
    if loop_limit is not None and loop > loop_limit: break
s.close()


def raw_value_tuples(raw_dict):
raw_coords = raw_dict['values']['frame']['raw']
x_y_tup = (raw_coords['x'],raw_coords['y'])
return x_y_tup

def heartbeat_loop(loops=None):
if loops is None:
    while True:
        query_tracker(message='{"category": "heartbeat"}')
        time.sleep(0.3)
else:
    for _ in range(loops):
        query_tracker(message='{"category": "heartbeat"}')
        time.sleep(0.3)


)
```